# Actions from gwt-platform are executed multiple times

Tags: google-app-engine, session, objectify, gwt-platform

I am using gwt-platform, objectify and appengine (java).

I am trying to create a user and session management system after best practices. I would like this to be a reusable module in applications.

I have, in my application, based on the Dispatch module in gwt-platform, a Login action and a Logout one.

When I enter the application, the login screen appears and everything works fine. If I navigate between presenters and after that I  press the Logout button, I see that the logout action is executed multiple times, or any other Action for that matter. 
The number of executions for an Action ( which should only run once ) seems to be directly proportional with the number of times I navigate between presenters.

The source code for the project is hosted at: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform-appengine-session-login-example/

If someone could give me some hints of what is wrong it would be great. Also, if someone would also like to contribute to the project,some help would be appreciated. Please email me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you add your EventHandler for the Logout button in the `onReset()` method.
However if you check the GWTP docs the `onReset()` method is called whenever you navigate to the presenter. So if you navigate to the presenter multiple times the `EventHandler` will be added multiple times and thus executed multiple times (directly proportional to the number of times you open the presenter).

Move the `EventHandler` out of the `onReset()` method into the `onBind()` method because `onBind()` is only called once in the presenter's life cycle and it is the place where you should add `EventHandlers`. In addition to this wrap it into `registerHandler()` method so it is automatically removed when the `onUnbind()` is called.

**FirstApplicationPresenter.java**:

```
@Override
protected void onBind() {
    super.onBind();
    getView().getLogoutBtn().setText("Logout "+username);
    registerHandler(getView().getLogoutBtn().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Logout action = new Logout();
                dispatchAsync.execute(action, logoutCallback);
            }
    }));
}

@Override
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the right answer. Any help is appreciated.